# Using IntegerPartitions for distinct integers

Tags: combinatorics, partitions, integer-sequence

What I would like to do is to find a way to test how many ways `m` **distinct** integers from the set `{1,..., n}` where `n ≥ m` can sum to a given integer `K`?

Comment: You want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018252/a-variation-of-integerpartition) and answers therein.

Comment: Take a look at http://oeis.org/A008289, fairly sure that's what you're asking for, and there's a *Mathematica* implementation.

Comment: you got so far as finding `IntegerPartitions`, so what did you try and whats the problem?

Answer (score 5):

When you say "how many ways", I interpret this to mean you want to count
the number of partitions, and do not necessarily need to find the partitions
themselves. Also, summing to the given integer $k$ only requires the set from
1 to $k$, rather than 1 to $n$. So assume $n\le k$.

In this case, you can use`PartitionsQ[k]`to find the number of partitions
of integer $k$ into distinct parts, which is Sloane's A000009.
https://oeis.org/A000009

```
PartitionsQ[Range[10]]
(* {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10} *)
```

However, you also state you want to use only a specified number $m$ of integers
from the set 1 to $k$.`PartitionsQ[k]`gives you the total count for all possible
$m$. The count for specific $m$ may be obtained by using generating functions.

The generating function corresponding to`PartitionsQ`has the following form.

```
Series[Product[1 + z^i, {i,1,k}], {z,0,k}]
```

The coefficient of $z^k$ in this series gives the number of ways of partitioning
$k$ into distinct parts.

```
Coefficient[Series[Product[1 + z^i, {i,1,k}], {z,0,k}], z, k]
```

For example, to find the number of partitions into distinct parts of $k=7$
you would use

```
Block[{z,k=7}, Coefficient[Series[Product[1 + z^i, {i,1,k}], {z,0,k}], z, k]]
```

The 5 partitions of $k=7$ into distinct integers are {7}, {6, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 3},
and {4, 2, 1}. To count how many partitions use $m$ distinct integers use the
following generating function.

```
Coefficient[Series[Product[1 + t*z^i, {i,1,k}], {z,0,k}], z, k]]
```

For the example $k=7$, the coefficient of $z^7$ in the resulting series is
$t + 3 t^2 + t^3$. Now look at the coefficients of powers of $t$, which are
1, 3, and 1. This means, from left to right, that there is one partition
of 7 into 1 distinct part, 3 partitions of 7 into 2 distinct parts, and
1 partition of 7 into 3 distinct parts.

Consider another example for $k=9$ and $m=3$. The generating function is

```
Block[{k=9,m=3}, Series[Product[1 + t*z^i, {i,1,k}], {z,0,k}]]
```

The coefficient of $z^{k=9}$ is $t + 4 t^2 + 3 t^3$. Hence, $k=9$ may be
formed by one set of 1 distinct integer from 1 to 9, that is, {9}.
Moreover, $k=9$ may be formed by four sets of 2 distinct integers from
1 to 9, that is, {8, 1}, {7, 2}, {6, 3}, {5, 4}. Finally, $k=9$ may be
formed by three sets of 3 distinct integers from 1 to 9, that is,
{6, 2, 1}, {5, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 2}.

These partitions may be found by using IntegerPartitions as follows.

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[9, {1}], Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]
Select[IntegerPartitions[9, {2}], Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]
Select[IntegerPartitions[9, {3}], Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]
```

For $n<k$, use the generating function

```
Series[Product[1 + t*z^i, {i, 1, n}], {z, 0, k}]
```

or, for example,

```
Select[IntegerPartitions[9, {2}, Range[n]], Length[#] == Length[Union[#]] &]
```